# How do I make a responsive margin which grows larger for larger screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I want a margin which will be close to 0% on small screen sizes and around 20% on large ones without using @media queries to force specific numbers for all specific screen sizes.

What I am imagining is some math equation that will turn a number like 300 (300px) to 0 (0%) and a number like 2000 (2000px) to 20 (20%)? However, I am no math genius so I am asking for your help please.

Currently I am using `margin: 0 10%;` which is an alright compromise, however, I still find that the margin is far to large on small screen sizes and far to small on large screen sizes

```css
:root {
  --page-margin: 10%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 var(--page-margin);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: have you ever looked into the CSS [clamp() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the CSS `clamp()` function. Set the minimum to 0 and the max to 20vw (equals 20% width of the viewport). Then calculate the average value with the max value - a certain pixel value (play around with it):

```css
:root {
  --page-margin: 10%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 clamp(0vw, 20vw - 100px ,20vw);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This worked like charm! Do you know if clamp() is supported on all browsers? When I checked caniuse.com it said it was in techological preview on safari whatever that means

Comment: All major browsers with exception of deprecated IE and Opera mini (which also do not support calc function). So it really should not be an issue.

Comment: Safari 16 is in tech preview, not the feature. That's the browser version. https://caniuse.com/css-math-functions